# Como realizar transcribir consulta sql en Laravel??

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Mi consulta es la siguiente como puedo transcribir el siguiente SQL para laravel:

```
 SELECT 
 movimientos.descripcion as Detalle,
 desde.descripcion AS desde,
 destino.descripcion AS destino
 FROM movimientos
 JOIN almacens desde on desde.id_almacen=movimientos.id_ubicacion_inicial
 JOIN almacens destino on destino.id_almacen=movimientos.id_ubicacion_final
 where movimientos.estado=1
```

Usando el ELOQUENT

Comment: indica cuales son exactamente los nombres de tus tablas para poder ayudarte así me resultan confusos

Comment: ROBERTO BECEZERRA ARZAB te postee una respuesta espero te ayude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería algo como esto:

```
    $movimientos=DB::table('movimientos')
    ->join('almacens as desde','movimientos.id_ubicacion_inicial','=','desde.id_almacen')
    ->join('almacens as destino','movimientos.id_ubicacion_final','=','destino.id_almacen')
    ->select('movimientos.descripcion as Detalle','desde.descripcion as desde','destino.descripcion as destino')
    ->where([
           ['movimientos.estado','=',1],
           ]);
```

Comment: Disculpad entonces.

Answer (score 1):

> Si tu modelo se Llama Movimiento puedes hacerlo del modo siguiente

```
$resultado = Movimiento::select('movimientos.descripcion as Detalle','desde.descripcion as desde','destino.descripcion as destino')
    ->from('movimientos')
    ->join('almacens as desde','movimientos.id_ubicacion_inicial','=','desde.id_almacen')
    ->join('almacens as destino','movimientos.id_ubicacion_final','=','destino.id_almacen')
    ->where('movimientos.estado','=',1);
    ->get();
```